# Wpf combobox Itemstringformat date

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Combobox items binding in database:

```
using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tedavi_tarih FROM " + mw.db_name + ".tedavi Where hasta_id= '" + mw.hasta_id + "' ORDER BY tedavi_tarih DESC";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connect))
    {
        connect.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            combobox_tarih.Items.Add(reader.GetString("tedavi_tarih"));
        }
        connect.Close();
    }
}
```

tedavi_tarih format is Date but when I add it to combobox, it displays as "5.01.2018 00:00:00". I want to display only "5.01.2018". I tried this in XAML:

```
ItemStringFormat="dd/M/yyyy"
```

It doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reader.GetString("tedavi_tarih")` returns a string. It doesn't return a `DateTime`. A string doesn't become a `DateTime` when you try to convert it to a string using a `DateTime` format string.

If the "tedavi_tarih" column really is Date, this should work:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    combobox_tarih.Items.Add(reader.GetDateTime("tedavi_tarih"));
}
```

If by "format as Date" you really mean that it's a date formatted as a string, you'll have to use `DateTime.TryParse()`. Let me know.

---

**Obligatory warning:** The code below is a SQL injection vulnerability. It is very bad, very dangerous practice. You should not concatenate SQL strings. [You should use SqlParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) instead.

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tedavi_tarih FROM " + mw.db_name + ".tedavi Where hasta_id= '" 
             + mw.hasta_id + "' ORDER BY tedavi_tarih DESC";
```

Comment: Your answer is works! But now I'm trying to access the combobox value and it is return to "5.01.2018 00:00:00" . Access code: combobox_tarih.SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: It isn’t return to anything. It’s s DateTime. You can format it however you like.